# ASCII Character set issue in Java

Tags: java, ascii

Consider the simple example:

```
System.out.println("¬");
System.out.println((int)(('¬')));
System.out.println((char)170);
```

The output I get is as follows (in order from the sample code):

```
¬
172
ª
```

Why is this occurring? I looked into the [ASCII chart for character 170](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/logical-negation-symbol-ascii-code-170.html), and it says that it is indeed a `¬`. Even (on Windows), when one does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+170, I get `¬`.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: ASCII only defines 128 characters (codes 0-127), so 170 is not a standard ASCII character. The little a seems to be character 170 in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: The link is dead and describes ASCII Extended, not ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's (internal) default charset is UTF-16 (Unicode).

170 decimal is AA hex, so your character is FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR, see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00aa/index.htm).

The [documentation of Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) states:

char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: This is not true, Java's **internal** encoding is UTF-16 and the default for `PrintStream` depends on the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No. Java is UTF if you don't explicitly specify otherwise. Have a look at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ and you will see that unicode U+00AC (==172) is the negation sign and unicode U+00AA (==170) is the feminine ordinal character.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) has only 128 characters.

So you are looking up tables in some kind of "enhanced ASCII" table, probably the Latin-1 / ISO-8859-1 character set, while Java uses **Unicode**, usually the two byte Unicode variant.

[List of Unicode characters (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) agrees with what Java is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to print it in a system.out, then use the unicode equivalent as follows;

```
   System.out.println("\u00AC");
```

Hope this helps.